# 'The literal of type int is out of range' con número enteros pequeños (2 dígitos)

Tags: java

Creo una variable de tipo **int** y le doy un valor de, por ejemplo, "06" u algún otro valor con un "0" delante, y esto debería de marcar error por el hecho de si es un numero entero no puede tener un cero a la izquierda, pero todo funciona bien. En cambio, si le damos el valor: "08" o "09", te salta un error indicando que esta fuera de rango.

El error debería de marcarlo con toda la secuencia desde "01" hasta "09", ¿por qué solo con el "08" y el "09"?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  int test = 08;
}
```

> The literal 08 of type int is out of range

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254077/int-with-leading-zeroes-unexpected-result/8254103#8254103

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`08`, en contra de lo que tu crees, es un [**número literal en formato octal**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_octal). Java interpreta como números en ese formato todos los que empiezan con un `0`.

En este formato, los dígitos individuales van **desde el `0` al `7`**.

De ahí el error: `08` **no es un número en formato octal válido**, lo mismo que `09`. Si son correctos, por ejemplo, `05' o`03`.

Comment: !Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 3):

Escribiendo en google esto: literal int java leading zeros (ya que la pregunta me sono interesante), cai en esta respuesta [en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8254103/73749).

Alli aclara que si se pone un 0 adelante, el valor se toma como un octal. Y los octales son numeros de 0 a 7.

Por lo tanto, tu 6, es un 6 octal, no un 6 en base diez.

Jon en una [respuesta posterior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8254117/73749), nos provee un link a la [documentacion de java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#3.10.1).

Alli aclara un poco mas la respuesta, diciendo que un 0 solo, o los numeros del 1 al 9 se toman como decimales, y cualquier numero que comience con 0 se toma como octal.

Como curiosidad, aclara que un 00 es un 0 en octal, como si realmente fuera muy diferente a un 0 en decimal.

Comment: Ahora todo mas claro. Muchas gracias por el post.